# Python program disregards button input

Tags: python, twitter, raspberry-pi, bots

I'm new to python and linux, and I recently set up a twitter bot with my Raspberry Pi to mess around and have fun with. I want to set up a system where my RasPi sends a tweet every time I press a button. I followed the instructions on https://raspberrypihq.com/use-a-push-button-with-raspberry-pi-gpio to set up the basic input.

I have two .py files, tweet_test.py and buttonPress.py

tweet_test:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import random
from twython import Twython


# your twitter consumer and access information goes here
apiKey = ''
apiSecret = ''
accessToken = ''
accessTokenSecret = ''

api = Twython(apiKey,apiSecret,accessToken,accessTokenSecret)


messages = [
    "A button was pressed!!",
    "My creator pressed a button.",
    "This tweet was triggered by a button press.",
]

message = random.choice(messages)

api.update_status(status=message)
print("Tweeted: " + message)
```

buttonPress:

```
import tweet_test
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO #Import Raspberry Pi GPIO library


def button_callback(channel):
    tweet_test
    print("Button was pushed!")

GPIO.setwarnings(False) #Ignore warning for now
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD) #Use physical pin numbering
GPIO.setup(10, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_DOWN) #Set pin 10 to be an 
input pin and set initial value to be pulled low (off)

GPIO.add_event_detect(10,GPIO.RISING,callback=button_callback) #Set up 
event on pin 10 rising edge

message = input("Press enter to quit\n\n") #Run until someone presses 
enter

GPIO.cleanup() #Clean Up
```

However, when I run buttonPress.py in the command line, the first thing it does is tweet, without even having received any input from the button. Then, it begins receiving button inputs, but doesn't tweet anything. Please help!

Sample output:

```
user1@raspberrypi:~/TwitterBot $ sudo python buttonPress.py
Tweeted: A button was pressed!!
Press enter to quit

Button was pushed!
Button was pushed!
Button was pushed!
```

Comment: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You import tweet_test.py at the very beginning and it will run first, which will run as exactly it is supposed to do, i.e. to send a tweet. You need to wrap the tweeting part as a function so that it only run when it is called:

### In tweet_test.py

```
def tweet():
    message = random.choice(messages)
    api.update_status(status=message)
    print("Tweeted: " + message)
```

### In buttonPress.py

Call the tweet() function in your button_callback like this:

```
def button_callback(channel):
    tweet()
    print("Button was pushed!")
```

Alternatively, just move the tweeting part to the button_call function, and combined both into your button_callback:

```
def button_callback(channel):
    message = random.choice(messages)
    api.update_status(status=message)
    print("Button was pushed! Tweeted: %s" % message)
```

### Update

Please also change the line `import tweet_test` to `from tweet_test import *`

Comment: It removed the problem of it tweeting at the start of the program, but now it shows the message: Traceback (most recent call last): File "buttonPress.py", line 6, in button_callback tweet()      NameError: global name 'tweet' is not defined

Comment: What message? Your program has input("Press enter to quit"), of course it will show that.

Comment: sorry, I accidentally pressed enter. I edited the previous comment to include the entirety of the error message

Comment: Oh, I forgot to ask you to change the line `import tweet_test` to `from tweet_test` import *`.